# How to deploy with git the Orchard CMS and customs modules to Azure WebSite and Storage?

Tags: azure, deployment, orchardcms, azure-web-app-service

I have git repository with a custom module and many other modules linked (Contrib.Taxonomies [modified], Contrib.ImageField, DotLess,  FeaturedItemSlider and other) and custom theme. It is merged with Orchard `1.5.x` branch. Currently the module only works with Orchard 1.5.1. I hope to upgrade to Orchard 1.7. The module uses Nuget to get some packages. It uses `.deployment`:

```
[config]
project= src\Orchard.Web
```

I want to deploy to Azure WebSite and use Azure storage. I'd like to use git deployment of Azure WebSite.

How to do it correctly? I've been trying some help topics for some days and I get some errors every now and then. What are correct steps to do it?

It looks like I need to modify source code of Orchard.Azure so that it can be used in Azure WebSite.

Also if I deploy branch with all source code it takes about 900MB on Azure WebSite. If I deploy `build\stage` it takes about 300MB. So I tried to deploy separate repository (submodule of the first) but I failed to build it as it has nuget dependencies.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Recently there have been new changes made to Orchard cms and it has new implementation for Azure services. It now requires to be merged with `1.x` branch as this func seems to be released in 1.7.1. Also there are a set of new articles related to Azure-Orchard func: http://goo.gl/u5neLv and http://goo.gl/Lr5D9M and http://goo.gl/StvavC .